# preserving size after rotating image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary image lu and when I rotate the image the size of the image lu changes but i need to preserve the size of the image :

```
m=2048;
n=3072;
ODcenter =1.0e+03 *[2.0345    0.9985]
OD=ODcenter ;
X=zeros(m,n); %% m,n is size of image
t = 0:.1:2*pi;
ODradius = norm(ODcenter(2) - ODcenter(1)) / 2;
xm2 = round(2*ODradius*cos(t)+OD(1));
ym2 = round(2*ODradius*sin(t)+OD(2));



 imCircleAlphaData2 = roipoly(X,xm2,ym2);
 figure; imshow(imCircleAlphaData2);
 lu=imCircleAlphaData2;

mask1 = true(size(lu));  %# Create a matrix of true values the same size

mask1(ODcenter(2):end,:) = false;   %# Set the lower half to false
lu(~mask1) = 0;  %# Set all elements in lu corresponding to mask 1==0

mask2 = true(size(lu));
mask2(:,ODcenter(1):end) = false;   %# Set the right of the upper half to false
lu(~mask2) = 0;  %# Set all elements in lu corresponding mask 2==0
figure;
imshow(lu); % shows left upper

lurot= imrotate(lu,45);
 figure,imshow(lurot)
```

Size of lurot and lu is different . How can I preserve the size of image even if some part of image will be cropped after rotation

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have two options with Matlab [`imrotate`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html):

- Use `crop` which will make the output image the same size as the input image, cropping the rotated image to make it fit
- Use `loose` which will make the output image large enough to contain the entire original rotated image. Generally, this will make the output image larger than the input image.

```
lurot= imrotate(lu,45,'nearest','crop');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried rotating the cone (i.e image lu which is 1/4 of a circle) in clockwise direction using: 
lurot= imrotate(lu,-45,'nearest','crop');              figure,imshow(lu); hold on; plot(ODcenter(1), ODcenter(2),'*g');
figure, imshow(lurot); hold on; plot(ODcenter(1), ODcenter(2),'*r');  But the centre of the circle (ODcenter) no more lies on the tip of the rotated cone (lurot). Please suggest how can I keep ODcentre to lie on the tip of the lurot. Bassically I want to rotate lu keeping ODcentre fixed so that ODcentre always lie on the tip of the lurot

Comment: Kindly reply (@ Maurits and @ Mark Ransom) my above question

Comment: @Dev imrotate rotates around the center of the image. The content, your cone amongst others, is thus rotated with respect to this center. If you want the tip (green in your code) to be rotated similarly, you have to rotated its (x,y) coordinates yourself with respect to the image center.